# which timer job updates managed metadata in sharepoint 2010/2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have updated my Term Store in sharepoint 2013, but I am not getting this updated term store in my managed metadata column.
I would like to know which timer job updates these term store in sharepoint 2010/2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This job name is Taxonomy Update Scheduler. 
Please write [this article](http://davidfrette.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/taxonomy-update-scheduler%C2%A0timer%C2%A0job/)(it's for SharePoint 2010, but the same is true for SharePoint 2013)

Hope it help to you